# Simple calculator with validation

Tags: c#, validation, calculator

I've implemented a simple calculator in C# that takes in the left operand, the operator, and the right operand. Once the calculate button is clicked, I use four methods to validate the inputs:
1. The input is present
2. The operands are decimals
3. The operands are within the range 1-1000000
4. The operator is valid.

Right now all of these work *except* for #4, the operator validation. Where did I go wrong?

```
namespace SimpleCalculator
{
    public partial class SimpleCalculator : Form
    {
        public SimpleCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //click event with private method Calculate
        private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //validation for operands
            try
            {
                if (IsValidData())
                {
                    decimal operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal(operandTextBox1.Text);
                    string operator1 = operandTextBox1.Text;
                    decimal operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(operand2TextBox.Text);

                    Calculate(operand1, operand2);
                }
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A format exception has occurred. Please check all entries.", "Entry Error");
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An overflow exception has occurred. Please enter smaller values.", "Entry Error");
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dividing by zero is not allowed. Please check operand entries.", "Entry Error");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // methods for IsPresent, IsDecimal, IsWithinRange, and IsOperator
        public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
        {
            if(textBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field.", "Entry Error.");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox, string name)
        {
            decimal number = 0m;
            if(Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, out number))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal value.", "Entry Error");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
        public bool IsWithinRange(TextBox textBox, string name, decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
            if(number < min || number > max)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be between " + min.ToString() + " and " + max.ToString() + ".", "Entry Error");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        // this is the method that is returning false every time
        public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string name, string add, string subtract, string multiply, string divide)
        {
            string symbol = Convert.ToString(textBox.Text);
            if(symbol != add || symbol != subtract || symbol != multiply || symbol != divide)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be +, -, *, or /.", "Entry Error");
                textBox.Focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //public method that that uses created methods to check validity
        public bool IsValidData()
        {
            return
                //validate operand 1
                IsPresent(operandTextBox1, "Operand 1") &&
                IsDecimal(operandTextBox1, "Operand 1") &&
                IsWithinRange(operandTextBox1, "Operand 1", 1, 1000000) &&

                //validate operand 2
                IsPresent(operand2TextBox, "Operand 2") &&
                IsDecimal(operand2TextBox, "Operand 2") &&
                IsWithinRange(operand2TextBox, "Operand 2", 1, 1000000) &&

                //validate operator
                IsOperator(operatorTextBox, "Operator", "+", "-", "*", "/");
        }

        //private method that does the calculations
        private void Calculate(decimal operand1, decimal operand2)
        {
            //switch statement that used the operator to perform calculations
            //also displays error message if wrong operator is used
            switch (operatorTextBox.Text)
            {
                case "+":
                    resultTextBox.Text = (operand1 + operand2).ToString("f4");
                    break;
                case "-":
                    resultTextBox.Text = (operand1 - operand2).ToString("f4");
                    break;
                case "*":
                    resultTextBox.Text = (operand1 * operand2).ToString("f4");
                    break;
                case "/":
                    resultTextBox.Text = (operand1 / operand2).ToString("f4");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("You can only use +, -, *, or /");
                    break;
            }

            operandTextBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void clearResult(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resultTextBox.Text = "";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: operator validation when wrong in what case? could you please given an example for that? because your code look OK with the logic.

Comment: yes, so there are four operators that are valid: +, -, *, /.  And no matter which one I enter I get the message box that says I didn't enter the correct operator. I tried all for operators and they all return  true in the IsOperator method instead of false. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### 1. About your question( validation operator is wrong):

From your condition:

> if(symbol != add || symbol != subtract || symbol != multiply || symbol
>   != divide)

you are checking if the symbol is not 1 of 4 operators then it will return false. Then the condition is always true because every symbol with differrence with 1 of 4 operators.
You should AND conditions instead of OR in this case:

```
if (symbol != add && symbol != subtract && symbol != multiply && symbol != divide)
```

### 2. Code smell:

- You are using too many magic values.
- You should define enum/list orconstants for them, anh for operators also.
- You should follow coding convention also.

Example:

Bellow variable is redundant:

> string operator1 = operandTextBox1.Text;

Your variable name are not consistent:

> ```
>     operand**2**TextBox
>     operandTextBox**1**
> ```

You should define some constant for your magic values. Ex: "Operand 1" is magic value.

You can define a list of operators instead of use many operator strings. Then next time, if you want more operators( % for an example). And your operator validation also become easier:

```
readonly List<string> operators = new List<string> { "+", "-", "*", "/" };

public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string name)
{
    string symbol = Convert.ToString(textBox.Text);
    if (!operators.Contains(symbol))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name + " must be +, -, *, or /.", "Entry Error");
        textBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

P/S: This is just some ideas after a quickly review. You can look back your code based on my ideas and refactor it more.

Comment: Also, if I use && I won't get an error because it wants all of those values?

Comment: Wow, I changed the or's to and's and it totally works! I really hope that this comes easier to me in the future. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, As I mentioned, I updated my answer with some coding smell. You can a look on it. P/S: if my answer is helpful, could you please mark it as "accepted"? If you need any supporting from me, you are always welcome.

Comment: We don't fix bugs on Code Review if they are known and OP is askting for it... in case you're wondering what the DV is for.

Comment: oh, sorry, thought this would be a good place to go for help. I'll check out the rules in depth. Also, I clicked the check mark but until I get to a certain reputation, I don't think it counts my vote. I'll try again.  I still appreciate your help. I just can't wait until I get to a place where I would see the flaw in my logic.